# cannot deploy on jboss gatein server

Tags: java, jboss, war, gatein

My war successfully deployed in tomee, but when I try to deploy it in jboss gatein, I get next log:

```
2013-08-01 16:04:09,240 ERROR [org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.AbstractKernelController] (HDScanner) Error installing to Start: name=vfs:///D:/java/GateIn-3.2.0.Final-jbossas6/server/default/deploy/jsfbootstrap.war_WeldBootstrapBean state=Create: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408 Unsatisfied dependencies for type [Logger] with qualifiers [@Default] at injection point [[field] @Inject private com.rkovacevic.jsfbootstrap.service.MemberRegistration.log]
at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPoint(Validator.java:305) [:6.0.0.Final]
at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateBean(Validator.java:139) [:6.0.0.Final]
. . .
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [:1.7.0_13]

2013-08-01 16:04:09,265 WARN  [org.jboss.profileservice.deployment.hotdeploy.HDScanner] (HDScanner) Scan failed: org.jboss.deployers.client.spi.IncompleteDeploymentException: Summary of incomplete deployments (SEE PREVIOUS ERRORS FOR DETAILS):

DEPLOYMENTS MISSING DEPENDENCIES:
  Deployment "jboss-injector:appName=jsfbootstrap,module=jsfbootstrap" is missing the following dependencies:
    Dependency "<UNKNOWN jboss-injector:appName=jsfbootstrap,module=jsfbootstrap>" (should be in state "Installed", but is actually in state "** UNRESOLVED Demands 'jboss-switchboard:appName=jsfbootstrap,module=jsfbootstrap' **")
  Deployment "jboss-injector:topLevelUnit=jsfbootstrap.war,unit=jsfbootstrap.war,bean=CalculatorImpl,interceptor=org.jboss.weld.

integration.ejb.SessionBeanInterceptor" is missing the following dependencies:

more with same errors...

DEPLOYMENTS IN ERROR:
  Deployment "<UNKNOWN jboss-injector:topLevelUnit=jsfbootstrap.war,unit=jsfbootstrap.war,bean=CalculatorImpl,interceptor=org.jboss.weld.integration.ejb.SessionBeanInterceptor>" is in error due to the following reason(s): ** UNRESOLVED Demands 'jboss-switchboard:appName=jsfbootstrap,module=jsfbootstrap' **

  more with same errors...

  Deployment "<UNKNOWN jboss.j2ee:jar=jsfbootstrap.war,name=CalculatorImpl,service=EJB3>" is in error due to the following reason(s): ** UNRESOLVED Demands 'jboss-injector:bean=CalculatorImpl,interceptor=org.jboss.weld.integration.ejb.interceptor.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor,topLevelUnit=jsfbootstrap.war,unit=jsfbootstrap.war' **, ** UNRESOLVED Demands 'jboss-injector:bean=CalculatorImpl,interceptor=org.jboss.weld.integration.ejb.SessionBeanInterceptor,topLevelUnit=jsfbootstrap.war,unit=jsfbootstrap.war' **

at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.checkComplete(DeployersImpl.java:1370) [:2.2.0.GA]
. . .
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [:1.7.0_13]
```

I got this example here - I forked this project https://github.com/rkovacevic/JSFBootstrap 
and just add some ejb3 beans. As I said, this war successfully deploying in TomEE...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that some libs like portlet-api, portletbridge-api etc were missing in my server\lib folder, see my another question:

[GateIn Quickstarts: can't deploy JSF2 HelloWorld example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18017839/gatein-quickstarts-cant-deploy-jsf2-helloworld-example)